# Does apple allow games made using WkWebView in the app store?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, wkwebview, appstore-approval

I'm working on trying to find a good solution to making a cross platform application for desktop and mobile and web. Ive narrowed down my languages choices to JavaScript or C++.

Using JavaScript, it works in the web natively, can be packaged for desktops using Electron, and be wrapped in a WebView for mobile. if I use JavaScript, ideally I would like to write all my UI using HTML and CSS, which rules out things like React Native.

Using C++ I would need to change code based on each platform, my main concern with C++ is that I would need to write a backend for OpenGL, OpenGL ES, and Metal. I would like to avoid having to rewrite parts of my application as much as possible. Another thing im not very excited about but am ok with is that I would still need Objective-C and Java involved for IOS and Android.

I have been playing around with the JavaScript option using Electron and WKWebView for IOS, and it all works exactly how I want it to. This is where my concern comes in, Apple's Review Guidelines say that they wont accept apps that are simply repackaged websites, but they also talk about HTML5 games being allowed as long as they are not presented in a store like way. Its very confusing to me, i'm not exactly packaging a website, cause it will be a game designed specifically for mobile. and games don't typically use native looking UI, so I don't know whether this would be accepted or not.

I'm having a hard time understanding the guidelines, Does apple allow games made with HTML5 packaged in a WebView, or is it going to be rejected for being in a WebView?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Apple's review policies can only be answered by Apple.

Comment: Why not use Unreal Engine or Unity3D? They support ALL platforms easily!.. You have the ability to detect what platform you're running on as well.. and you can write the code in C# (Unity) or C++ (Unreal).. but Unreal doesn't "require" coding.. Both engines have advantages and disadvantages.. I like unreal more but currently doing a project in Unity and it's not bad either.. Engine does all the physics and stuff for you.. all you have to do really is logic and stuff and it will support ALL platforms (web and mobile).

Comment: @Brandon I really wish i could just use one of the big engines, but i am more of a systems programmer, i prefer doing everything from scratch.